# calculating Euclidean distance between two image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I want to calculate the Euclidean distance between two images in Matlab. I find some examples and I've try them but they are not correct.
The result of this Euclidean distance should be between `0` and `1` but with two different ways I reached to different solutions.
The first algorithm gives me a 4 digit number such as `2000` and other digits like this and by the other way I reached numbers such as `0.007`
What is wrong with it?

This is one of those algorithms I mentioned:

```
Im1 = imread('1.jpeg');
Im2 = imread('2.jpeg');

Im1 = rgb2gray(Im1);
Im2 = rgb2gray(Im2);

hn1 = imhist(Im1)./numel(Im1);
hn2 = imhist(Im2)./numel(Im2);

% Calculate the Euclidean distance
f = sum((hn1 - hn2).^2)
```

Comment: Very similar question can be find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475815/comparing-two-image-using-histogram?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the final line of code needs a sqrt command:

```
f = sum(sqrt(hn1-hn2).^2);
```

check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)

You can also use the **norm** command

```
f = norm(hn1-hn2);
```

These [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368597/euclidean-distance-between-two-vectors-single-row-matrix) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342457/how-to-calculate-euclidean-length-of-a-matrix-without-loops) can be useful.

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to vote you,and i'm sorry:(. thanks a milion for your great help

Comment: In some specific case,  the result of the euclidean distance between 2 arrays can be an array ? or it should be always scalar ?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I'm not sure where to begin but here are some things that you should think about:

1: You're normalising your histograms incorrectly. You want them to have unit L1-norm:

```
hn1 = imhist(Im1);
hn2 = imhist(Im2);
hn1 = hn1/numel(hn1);
hn2 = hn2/numel(hn2);
```

2: Taking L2-distance between histograms doesn't really make sense (what is an euclidian distance between two distributions really?). You should rather take a look at something like a L1 or Chi-2 distance, or use an intersection kernel. L1 would be

```
f=norm(hn1-hn2,1);
```

3: If you really do want it to be L2 euclidian distance, the last line should be

```
f=norm(hn1-hn2);
```

but then you should rather L2-normalize the histogram:

```
hn1 = imhist(Im1);
hn2 = imhist(Im2);
hn1 = hn1/norm(hn1);
hn2 = hn2/norm(hn2);
```

4: Please try to be clearer in the formulation of your questions - it was a bit hard to decode :). If your would have mentioned the application - I could have given some additional pointers. :)

Comment: thanks. i want to write the vsumm algorithm. i must compute the pairwise distance of consecutive frames in the extracted sample,
according to Euclidean distance. while there is a threshold 0.5 ,when ever the Euclidean distance go above 0.5 , k should be increased.

Comment: I see. In that case I would vote for sticking with Euclidian distance, (as it is justified by the k-means clustering step) even if it is not the most suitable distance measure for comparing histograms.

Comment: thank you. do you have any idea for this algorithm? i'm writing it and it's a little hard. do you have any guidance?

Comment: dear kamjagin <br> can you please answer to my other question which i asked in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563980/calculate-the-normalized-histogram-of-image-in-hsv-space-in-matlab