# Calculate the Normalized Histogram of Image in hsv space in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm writing an algorithm from an article. I did everything that was in the article untill now, but my answer is wrong and I can't understand why.

According to article there are these steps:

1. Input  a video data and extract it to frames according to a special rate (I've done this correctly and the result is 500 frames which are images in `jpeg`. I don't have a problem in this part)
2. Use the color histogram because the color feature is the most expressive feature. For 
   this color histogram in hsv color space only the hue component should be calculated.
3. The quantization of the color histogram is set to 16 color bins
4. The meaningless frames which are monochromatic frames due to fade-in/fade-out 
   effects should be removed. This is done by computing the standard deviation of the frame feature vector.

I've done all of the above as it was mentioned in the article. The standard deviation for monochromatic frames should be equal to zero or a small value but mine is `1500`, `1000`, `1700` and numbers like these. What is wrong with this code?

```
b=imread('pics\image-1.jpeg');
hsv = rgb2hsv(b);
h = hsv(:,:,1);
hHist = hist(h(:),16);
%computing standard deviation
f=std2(hHist)
```

Comment: I think, you have problem with over- and underexposed parts: they have wrong h-data. You can try to exclude from histogram low and high ends by threshold near 10. Also, why do you do 16-bit histogram? Is your original image 48-bit?

Comment: what are these 'underexposed parts'? i need  16-bit histogram cause the article wants the pic to be in 16 bits , i do not know if my original image is 48 bit or not!?

Comment: 1. If your original image is 24-bit RGB, you don't need 16-bit H histogram. 2. look at your histogram & H-component. I'm sure that they have non-monochromatic parts.

Comment: thanks alot for your help:) <br>yes you were correct the original image was 8 bit RGB(it was written in photoshop) but the article said the hsv image should have 16 bits,what should i do?

Comment: You can do 16-bit histogram for decreasing rounding errors (H can even be float). But for your case 8-bit histogram would be enough.