# Finding the distance between two images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, euclidean-distance

I would like to find the distance between two images in matlab where each one is represented by (24x32x3) matrix. Any Idea how to apply any distance technique (ex. euclidean distance) to get the difference in one value?

Thanks

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554781/calculating-euclidean-distance-between-two-image-in-matlab) is what you need.

Comment: Being a bit more specific than in the post mentioned, do : `f = sum(sqrt(hn1(:)-hn2(:)).^2);`

Comment: But this doesn't work with multi-dimensional matrices. I want one value at the end for the distance between the two images.